# Get historical Klines for multiple pair combination with a base (USDT)

Tags: python, binance, binance-api-client

At the moment I have a a very manual process for returning a single pair of historical candlestick data from Binance e.g AVAXUSDT

I would like to be able to get candlestick data from Binance for multiple pair combinations with USDT (or other) as the base currency e.g. AVAXUSDT, LUNAUSDT, ADAUSDT etc.

Here's part of my script returning the single pair

```
candlesticks = client.get_historical_klines("AVAXUSDT", Client.KLINE_INTERVAL_12HOUR, "1 Jan, 2019", "18 Sep, 2021")
```

How might I get many pairs?

Answer (score 2):

A possible solution:

```py
import binance
import time

# tqdm not necessary, is only used for showing progress during klines iteration
from tqdm import tqdm

def multiple_klines(quote_currency: str) -> dict:
    klines = {}

    # You don't need API key/secret for this type of requets
    client = binance.Client()

    # Extract trading pairs from exchange information
    exchange_info = client.get_exchange_info()
    symbols = [x['symbol'] for x in exchange_info['symbols']]

    # Filter list
    selected_symbols = list(filter(lambda x: x.endswith(quote_currency), symbols))

    # Iterate over filtered list of trading pairs
    for symbol in tqdm(selected_symbols):
        klines[symbol] = client.get_historical_klines(
            symbol, client.KLINE_INTERVAL_12HOUR,
            "1 Jan, 2019", "18 Sep, 2021"
        )

        # Prevent exceeding rate limit:
        if int(client.response.headers['x-mbx-used-weight-1m']) > 1_000:
            print('Pausing for 30 seconds...')
            time.sleep(30)

    return klines

klines_dict = multiple_klines('USDT')
```

Notes:

- No authentication needed (API key/secret) for this type of calls. But be aware of the [rate limits](https://binance-docs.github.io/apidocs/spot/en/#limits) (allowed calls to the API per minute).
- Your selected time span and interval for the klines call will not contain all the data from start to end, because the [API](https://binance-docs.github.io/apidocs/spot/en/#kline-candlestick-data) only returns 500 "rows" (per default, 1000 max). Your selected time span is 992 days, and therefore 1984 "rows" with a 12 hour interval.
- Returns a `dict` containing the trading pairs (e.g. `BTCUSDT`) as key and the klines data as value.
- Klines data is returned as `nested list`. You can find the documentation [here](https://binance-docs.github.io/apidocs/spot/en/#kline-candlestick-data).

Answer (score 0):

You can literate list of altcoins like this:

```
alts_list = ['1INCH', 'ADA', 'ATOM', 'ANKR', 'ALGO', 'AVAX', 'AAVE','AUDIO', 'AR',
            'BAT', 'CHZ', 'COTI', 'CAKE','FTT','FLOW','APE','AGLD', 'BNB','ETH',
           'DOT', 'DOGE', 'EOS', 'ETC', 'ENJ', 'EGLD',  'FTM', 'FIL', 'AXS',
            'HOT', 'IOTA', 'ICP', 'KSM', 'LINK', 'LTC', 'LUNA','GALA', 'HBAR',
             'MATIC', 'MANA', 'NEO', 'NEAR', 'ONE', 'RVN', 'SAND', 'XMR','XTZ', 'ZEC',
             'SOL', 'TFUEL', 'THETA', 'UNI', 'VET', 'WAVES', 'XRP', 'XLM', 'ZIL'
     ] 
for alt in alts_list:
        klines = client.get_historical_klines(alt + "USDT", Client.KLINE_INTERVAL_1MINUTE,
                                              "250 minutes ago UTC")
```